# TCP Response Halting

Tags: c++, c++-cli

I am trying to send a tcp message to a server and get a response back, however when I am trying to read the server response, my program hangs. How can I fix this, am I doing something wrong?

Here is my code:

```
TcpClient^ client = gcnew TcpClient( "1.1.1.1", 888 );
NetworkStream^ stream = client->GetStream();
array<Byte>^data = SE::crypt(key + this->txtUsername->Text + "&" + this->txtPassword->Text + "&" + SE::Serialize("C"));
stream->Write( data, 0, data->Length );
data = gcnew array<Byte>(256);
String^ responseData = String::Empty;
Int32 bytes = stream->Read( data, 0, data->Length );
responseData = System::Text::Encoding::ASCII->GetString( data, 0, bytes );
Console::WriteLine( "Received: {0}", responseData );
client->Close();
```

My code halts at when I debug:

```
Int32 bytes = stream->Read( data, 0, data->Length );
```

Comment: Looks like you aren't getting a response back, otherwise it would return.

Answer (score 0):

The hanging may be a result of Read waiting for the entire data->Length to be received.  For example, if data->Length is 100 and the server responds with only 80 bytes, the Read command will block until the other 20 bytes are received.

In many protocols, there is a fixed length header that contains a response length.  That allows the receiver to first receive the fixed length header, then setup another Read of a variable length to get the remainder of the data.

Perhaps use Wireshark to monitor the IP traffic and verify the response length.